# NFS does not share a folder with name starting with DOT

Tags: linux, nfs, centos-5

I have two machines:

- NFS server `Linux: 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5  NFS: 3.2.22`
- NFS client `Linux: 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 NFS: 3.2.29`

And it was totally fine until someone created a directory with the name starting with DOT, for example:

```
/mnt/.DIRECTORY
```

This directory stays on the server but does not go to the client. It's invisible on clent NFS folder.

How could I make hidden NFS shared folder visible to client?

Comment: Is it just not visible by default (which would be expected given that it is a hidden directory) or did the mount actually not succeed? If you run 'ls -la /mnt' do you see the directory? If you run 'cd /mnt/.DIRECTORY' do you navigate there properly (and does a subsequent 'ls' show the contents from the share?)?

Comment: It's so confusing to not to check that by terminal commands. Thank you for your suggestion. "ls -la" works. I use midnight commander. And hidden files are alway visible. But on this server hidden files showing was turned off in MC.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help RandomMac.
There was no problem with NFC. Hidden files showing was turned off in MC. 
As always "ls -la" works.